# Controllability and observability from given transfer function

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, controller

Is it possible to determine whether system is uncontrollable or unobservable or both  from given transfer function in which there is pole zero cancellation?

for ex.transfer function like this [image]

Or it impossible to determine it's controllability and observability from given transfer function until it is already defined in State space model?

As @AJN pointed out for more clarity I'm adding one more example

[image]
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, after cancelling all the common factors (`(s+1)` in this example), a TF represents only the *controllable-and-observable* part of a system. If you are familiar with state space theory, read up on [Kalman Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition). The reference pointed to, in that article seems to be good read.

Comment: Thanks for reply !as you wrote if we check controllability and observability after cancellation of pole and zeroes then it will always comes out to be controllable and obserable but if we write directly state equation without pole zero cancellation then problem is that contrallibility and observability is different for different forms (diagonal form,controllable canonical form etc) State model ,that's why I asked whether is it possible to determine exactly about contrallibility and observability , although nice reference thanks again

Comment: "*problem is that contrallibility and observability is different for different forms (diagonal form,controllable canonical form etc)*":  I'm not sure what you mean; but controllability and observability is a property of the system. It should not change for different *forms* AFAIK. Can you add an example into the question ?

Comment: @AJN ,take a look ,I added another example

Comment: There may be some uniqueness theorem for state space to TF and TF to SS conversions. For systems with pole zero cancellation, the conversion may *not* be unique. This non uniqueness may be allowing you to form a controllable version and an observable version (thereby preventing you from finding out if it is uncontrollable or un-observable). I don't have a good text book source with me now to authoritatively answer your question. I think a source detailing the Kalman decomposition will lead to the answer to your question.